# How to create a node in another node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a circle, an SKShapeNode, and I want to create a child node inside it. How I can do this?

```
func AddCircle() {        
    Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circleRadius)
    Circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    Circle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.addChild(Circle)
    Circle.addChild(BooCharacter)     
}
```

**Main Character:**

```
func AddCharacter() {
    BooCharacter.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    BooCharacter.anchorPoint.y = 0
    BooCharacter.zRotation = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    BooCharacter.position.y += circleRadius
}
```

I want to create an object in my circle but I don't know how you write it.

For example, I've tried to add a rect inside of my circle:

```
func AddRect() {
   Rect = SKShapeNode()
   Rect.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x:0, y: 250, width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 64).CGPath
   Rect.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()      
}
func AddCircle() {        
    Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circleRadius)
    Circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    Circle.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.addChild(Circle)
    Circle.addChild(BooCharacter)
    Circle.addChild(Rect)
```

but it's still not working.

I want to create and add triangles inside of my circle like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're doing exactly the right thing, although I don't see where `BooCharacter` is being created – are you definitely creating that somewhere? Using `addChild()` to add a node to your scene, or to add one node to another node, is correct, and should work for all types of `SKNode`.

Comment: Upload your project to GitHub or Dropbox and I'll take a look. Please be clear what happens and what you expect to happen.

Comment: i can explain here if its ok ?

Comment: mail for dropbox link?

Comment: paul@hackingwithswift.com is fine. Or just post it here so others can look.

Comment: what happens : nothing , its even no showed my new node that i created. i tried to create rect and its not worked

Comment: @TowStarws , i sent you my project in dropbox

Comment: @omer15: Your code does almost nothing; it just sits there on the launch screen. I can't write your code for you – what exactly do you want help with? How do I trigger the situation you are having trouble with?

Comment: i will upload for you again.

Comment: @TowStraws: i need to create triangle into my circle